# Ruby on Rails Devise Error: no secure_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I just installed devise 3.1.1 and whenever I run "rails generate devise:install" I get an error saying that "Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer." 
I checked in my "Config/initializers/" folder but there is no "devise.rb" file to edit!
What should I do? please help me, I'm rails beginner and I searched everywhere but found no solution. thank you.

Comment: Is your devise gem installed correctly? Try `bundle update`

Comment: @RajeshKolappakam  Yes, I already did that, and I can see devise gem using the "gem list" as well. What I'm doing wrong? still getting error about secret_key!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move to your `routes.rb` file and comment this line

```
#devise_for :installs
```

Now move to your console/CMD and re-run  **rails generate devise:install**

if above does not fix your problem then manually change your devise gem version(in gem file)
  `gem 'devise', '3.0.3'` and then follow the step as I mentioned above.

Comment: It's a common issue when you go for using devise (updated one).

Comment: add me on facebook, I've the same name, search for me :P